# Generating recommendation model for a large dataset using spark

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying out to generate a simple ALS model using the spark documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html).
My first file(ratings.csv) has 20million UserID,MovID,Rat and can be downloaded [here](http://ml-20m.zip)

So I have the testing data which is a subset of ratings.csv. That test dataset can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_z7iObE9G7lTGtROG1LRmFONlk):
The test file has just the UserID, Movie ID column.

So to create training data we will have to filter ratings.csv.
The following code is working fine for a smaller case of 100,000 UserID,MovID rating. I am not able to generate the model for the big case. 
Please help with a pointer.

```
/**
  * Created by echoesofconc on 3/8/17.
  */
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.ALS
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating
import java.io._
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer


object Prateek_Agrawal_task1 {

  def dropheader(data: RDD[String]): RDD[String] = {
    data.mapPartitionsWithIndex((idx, lines) => {
      if (idx == 0) {
        lines.drop(1)
      }
      lines
    })
  }

  def create_training(ratings_split: RDD[Array[String]], ratings_testing: Array[Array[String]]) = {
    ratings_split.filter(x => {
      ratings_testing.exists(y =>
        (x(0) == y(0) && x(1) == y(1))
      ) == false
    })
  }
  def create_testing(ratings_split: RDD[Array[String]], ratings_testing: Array[Array[String]]) = {
    ratings_split.filter(x => {
      ratings_testing.exists(y =>
        (x(0) == y(0) && x(1) == y(1))
      ) == true
    })
  }
  def create_model(ratings_train:RDD[Array[String]],rank:Int,numIterations:Int ):org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel={
    val ratings = ratings_train.map(_ match { case Array(user,item,rate,temp) =>
      Rating(user.toInt, item.toInt, rate.toDouble)
    })
    val model = ALS.train(ratings, rank, numIterations, 0.01)
    return model
  }

  def print_results(final_predictions_adjusted:RDD[((Int, Int), Double)])={
    val rating_range=final_predictions_adjusted.map(x=>(x._2.toInt,1)).reduceByKey(_+_).sortByKey()
    val rating_range_till_4=rating_range.map{x=>
      var temp=x
      if (x._1==5){temp=(4,x._2)}
      temp
    }.reduceByKey(_+_)
    rating_range_till_4.sortByKey().foreach { x =>
      if(x._1==0)
        printf(">=0 and <1: " + x._2+"\n")
      if(x._1==1)
        printf(">=1 and <2: " + x._2+"\n")
      if(x._1==2)
        printf(">=2 and <3: " + x._2+"\n")
      if(x._1==3)
        printf(">=3 and <4: " + x._2+"\n")
      if(x._1==4)
        printf(">=4 " + x._2+"\n")
      if(x._1==5)
        printf("=5 " + x._2+"\n")
    }
  }
  case class User_mov_rat(UserID: Int, MovieID:Int, Pred_rating: Double)

  def print_outputfile(final_predictions_adjusted:RDD[((Int, Int), Double)])={
    val writer = new FileWriter(new File("./output.txt" ))
    writer.write("UserID,MovieID,Pred_rating\n")
    final_predictions_adjusted.collect().foreach(x=>{writer.write(x._1._1+","+x._1._2+","+x._2+"\n")})
    writer.close()
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Prateek_Agrawal_task1").setMaster("local[2]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)


   val file = "/Users/echoesofconc/Documents/USC_courses/INF553/ml-20m/ratings.csv"
   val test = "/Users/echoesofconc/Documents/USC_courses/INF553/Prateek_Agrawal_hw3/testing_20m.csv"

    val data = sc.textFile(file, 2).cache()
    val data_test = sc.textFile(test, 2).cache()

//    Drop Header
    val data_wo_header=dropheader(data).persist()
    val data_test_wo_header=dropheader(data_test).persist()
//    Create Training and testing data of the format (User ID, MovID, Rating, Time)

    val ratings_split = data_wo_header.map(line => line.split(",")).persist()
    data_wo_header.unpersist()
    data.unpersist()
    val ratings_testing = data_test_wo_header.map(line => line.split(",")).collect()
    data_test_wo_header.unpersist()
    data_test.unpersist()

    val ratings_train = create_training(ratings_split, ratings_testing).persist()
    val ratings_test=create_testing(ratings_split, ratings_testing)
    ratings_split.unpersist()
    ratings_test.unpersist()

//    Create the model using rating_train the training data
    val rank = 1
    val numIterations = 10

    val model=create_model(ratings_train,rank,numIterations)
    ratings_train.unpersist()

//    Average user,Rating from training this is for cases which are there in test but not rated by any user in training
    val user_avgrat=ratings_test.map(_ match { case Array(user, mov, rate, temp) =>(user.toInt, (rate.toDouble,1.0))}).reduceByKey((x,y)=>(x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2)).mapValues{ case (sum, count) => (1.0 * sum) / count }

//    Predict user_mov ratings
    val user_mov = data_test_wo_header.map(_.split(',') match { case Array(user, mov) =>
      (user.toInt,mov.toInt)
    })

    val predictions =
    model.predict(user_mov).map { case Rating(user, mov, rate) =>
      ((user, mov), rate)
    }
//    Combine Predictions and unpredicted user,Movies due to them being individual. Going forward we need to improve the accuracy for these predictions
    val user_mov_rat=user_mov.map(x=>(x,0.0))
    val predictions_unpredicted_combined= predictions.union(user_mov_rat).reduceByKey(_+_).map(x=>(x._1._1,(x._1._2,x._2)))
//    Combine average rating and predictions+unpredicted values
    val avg_rating_predictions_unpredicted_combined=predictions_unpredicted_combined.join(user_avgrat)
//    Generate final predictions RDD
    val final_predictions=avg_rating_predictions_unpredicted_combined.map{x=>
      var temp=((x._1,x._2._1._1),x._2._2)
      if(x._2._1._2==0.0){temp=((x._1,x._2._1._1),x._2._2)}
      if(x._2._1._2!=0.0){temp=((x._1,x._2._1._1),x._2._1._2)}
      temp
    }
//    Adjust for ratings above 5.0 and below 0.0
    val final_predictions_adjusted=final_predictions.map{x=>
      var temp=x
      if (x._2>5.0){temp=(x._1,5.0)}
      if (x._2<0.0){temp=(x._1,0.0)}
      temp
    }
    val ratesAndPreds = ratings_test.map(_ match { case Array(user, mov, rate, temp) => ((user.toInt,mov.toInt),rate.toDouble)}).join(final_predictions_adjusted)

    val MSE = ratesAndPreds.map { case ((user, product), (r1, r2)) =>
      val err = (r1 - r2)
      err * err
    }.mean()
    val RMSE=math.sqrt(MSE)
//    Print output.txt
    print_outputfile(final_predictions_adjusted)
//    Print the predictionresults
    print_results(final_predictions_adjusted.sortByKey())
    print(RMSE+"\n")
  }
}
```

In case someone thinks I should be doing a regex match I have tried that approach. BUt that dosen't seem to be a bottleneck.

I only need to complete the create model part on which I am stuck for the big dataset. Can somebody help.

EDIT:
Another approach I tried which is much faster by using broadcast variables. But it's been running for 12 hrs with no signs of progress. On spark UI somehow the whole of the RDD(ratings.csv ~500MB) is not cached. Only around 64MB with 2.5 Million lines is being processed initially. I am using `--executor-memory -8g`. I have modified the `create_training create_testing` functions:

```
/**
  * Created by echoesofconc on 3/8/17.
  */
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.ALS
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating
import java.io._



object Prateek_Agrawal_task2 {

  def dropheader(data: RDD[String]): RDD[String] = {
    data.mapPartitionsWithIndex((idx, lines) => {
      if (idx == 0) {
        lines.drop(1)
      }
      lines
    })
  }
  def create_training(data_wo_header: RDD[String], data_test_wo_header: RDD[String],sc:SparkContext): RDD[String] = {

    val rdd2array = sc.broadcast(data_test_wo_header.collect())
    val training_set = data_wo_header.filter{
      case(x) => rdd2array.value.filter(y => x.indexOf(y.toString())==0).length == 0
    }
    return training_set
  }
  def create_test(data_wo_header: RDD[String], data_test_wo_header: RDD[String],sc:SparkContext): RDD[String] = {

    val rdd2array = sc.broadcast(data_test_wo_header.collect())
    val training_set = data_wo_header.filter{
      case(x) => rdd2array.value.filter(y => x.indexOf(y.toString())==0).length != 0
    }
    return training_set
  }

  def create_model(ratings_train:RDD[String],rank:Int,numIterations:Int ):org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel={
    val ratings = ratings_train.map(_.split(',') match { case Array(user, item, rate, timestamp) =>
      Rating(user.toInt, item.toInt, rate.toDouble)
    })
    val model = ALS.train(ratings, rank, numIterations, 0.01)
    return model
  }

  def print_results(final_predictions_adjusted:RDD[((Int, Int), Double)])={
    val rating_range=final_predictions_adjusted.map(x=>(x._2.toInt,1)).reduceByKey(_+_).sortByKey()
    val rating_range_till_4=rating_range.map{x=>
      var temp=x
      if (x._1==5){temp=(4,x._2)}
      temp
    }.reduceByKey(_+_)
    rating_range_till_4.sortByKey().foreach { x =>
      if(x._1==0)
        printf(">=0 and <1: " + x._2+"\n")
      if(x._1==1)
        printf(">=1 and <2: " + x._2+"\n")
      if(x._1==2)
        printf(">=2 and <3: " + x._2+"\n")
      if(x._1==3)
        printf(">=3 and <4: " + x._2+"\n")
      if(x._1==4)
        printf(">=4 " + x._2+"\n")
      if(x._1==5)
        printf("=5 " + x._2+"\n")
    }
  }
  case class User_mov_rat(UserID: Int, MovieID:Int, Pred_rating: Double)

  def print_outputfile(final_predictions_adjusted:RDD[((Int, Int), Double)])={
    val writer = new FileWriter(new File("./output.txt" ))
    writer.write("UserID,MovieID,Pred_rating\n")
    final_predictions_adjusted.collect().foreach(x=>{writer.write(x._1._1+","+x._1._2+","+x._2+"\n")})
    writer.close()
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Prateek_Agrawal_task1").setMaster("local[2]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val file = "/Users/echoesofconc/Documents/USC_courses/INF553/ml-latest-small/ratings.csv"
    val test = "/Users/echoesofconc/Documents/USC_courses/INF553/Prateek_Agrawal_hw3/testing_small.csv"

//    val file = "/Users/echoesofconc/Documents/USC_courses/INF553/ml-20m/ratings.csv"
//    val test = "/Users/echoesofconc/Documents/USC_courses/INF553/Prateek_Agrawal_hw3/testing_20m.csv"

    val data = sc.textFile(file, 2).persist()
    val data_test = sc.textFile(test, 2).persist()

    //    Drop Header
    val data_wo_header=dropheader(data)
    val data_test_wo_header=dropheader(data_test)
    //    Create Traing and testing data of the format (User ID, MovID, Rating, Time)

    val ratings_train=create_training(data_wo_header,data_test_wo_header,sc).persist()
    val ratings_test=create_test(data_wo_header,data_test_wo_header,sc)
//    val ratings_test=create_test(data_wo_header,data_test_wo_header,sc)


//    data_test_wo_header.unpersist()
//    data_test.unpersist()
////    data.unpersist()
////    data_test.unpersist()
    //    Create the model using rating_train the training data
    val rank = 1
    val numIterations = 10
    val model=create_model(ratings_train,rank,numIterations)




    //    ratings_train.unpersist()
    //    model.save(sc, "target/tmp/myCollaborativeFilter")
    //    val Model = MatrixFactorizationModel.load(sc, "/Users/echoesofconc/myCollaborativeFilter")

    //    Average user,Rating from training
    val user_avgrat=ratings_test.map(_.split(",") match { case Array(user, mov, rate, temp) =>(user.toInt, (rate.toDouble,1.0))}).reduceByKey((x,y)=>(x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2)).mapValues{ case (sum, count) => (1.0 * sum) / count }
    //data
    //    Predict user_mov ratings
    val user_mov = data_test_wo_header.map(_.split(',') match { case Array(user, mov) =>
      (user.toInt,mov.toInt)
    })

    val predictions =
      model.predict(user_mov).map { case Rating(user, mov, rate) =>
        ((user, mov), rate)
      }
    //    Combine Predictions and unpredicted user,Movies due to them being individual. Going forward we need to improve the accuracy for these predictions
    val user_mov_rat=user_mov.map(x=>(x,0.0))
    val predictions_unpredicted_combined= predictions.union(user_mov_rat).reduceByKey(_+_).map(x=>(x._1._1,(x._1._2,x._2)))
    //    Combine average rating and predictions+unpredicted values
    val avg_rating_predictions_unpredicted_combined=predictions_unpredicted_combined.join(user_avgrat)
    //    Generate final predictions RDD
    val final_predictions=avg_rating_predictions_unpredicted_combined.map{x=>
      var temp=((x._1,x._2._1._1),x._2._2)
      if(x._2._1._2==0.0){temp=((x._1,x._2._1._1),x._2._2)}
      if(x._2._1._2!=0.0){temp=((x._1,x._2._1._1),x._2._1._2)}
      temp
    }
    //    Adjust for ratings above 5.0 and below 0.0
    val final_predictions_adjusted=final_predictions.map{x=>
      var temp=x
      if (x._2>5.0){temp=(x._1,5.0)}
      if (x._2<0.0){temp=(x._1,0.0)}
      temp
    }
    val ratesAndPreds = ratings_test.map(_.split(",") match { case Array(user, mov, rate, temp) => ((user.toInt,mov.toInt),rate.toDouble)}).join(final_predictions_adjusted)

    val MSE = ratesAndPreds.map { case ((user, product), (r1, r2)) =>
      val err = (r1 - r2)
      err * err
    }.mean()
    val RMSE=math.sqrt(MSE)
    //    Print output.txt
    print_outputfile(final_predictions_adjusted)
    //    Print the predictionresults
    print_results(final_predictions_adjusted.sortByKey())
    print(RMSE+"\n")
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the full code? Seems interesting, I will download the data set and give it a try. Are you running on clusters or in local machine? What happens when you are running on the big data set? Are you getting any memory exceptions?

Comment: By the way, the link for ratings.csv file is not working

Comment: I presume you are using this dataset: https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ right?

Comment: use Dataset based ML - you will get better performance

Comment: @Tawkir Yes its the movie lens data. I am running on my 8gb RAM local machine.

Comment: @Tawkir I was running into memory exceptions previously but now the processing is taking forever to run with sufficient memory. If you want I can send you the smaller dataset aswell.

Answer (score 0):

This worked out to be fine. It's using `join` to create testng training data

```
/**
  * Created by echoesofconc on 3/8/17.
  */
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.ALS
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel
import java.io._



object Prateek_Agrawal_task1 {

  def dropheader(data: RDD[String]): RDD[String] = {
    data.mapPartitionsWithIndex((idx, lines) => {
      if (idx == 0) {
        lines.drop(1)
      }
      lines
    })
  }

  def create_training(ratings_split: RDD[Array[String]], ratings_testing: Array[Array[String]]) = {
    ratings_split.filter(x => {
      ratings_testing.exists(y =>
        (x(0) == y(0) && x(1) == y(1))
      ) == false
    })
  }
  def create_testing(ratings_split: RDD[Array[String]], ratings_testing: Array[Array[String]]) = {
    ratings_split.filter(x => {
      ratings_testing.exists(y =>
        (x(0) == y(0) && x(1) == y(1))
      ) == true
    })
  }
  def create_model(ratings_train:RDD[((String, String), (String, String))],rank:Int,numIterations:Int ):org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel={
    val ratings = ratings_train.map(_ match { case ((user,item),(rate,temp)) =>
      Rating(user.toInt, item.toInt, rate.toDouble)
    })
    val model = ALS.train(ratings, rank, numIterations, 0.01)
    return model
  }

  def print_results(final_predictions_adjusted:RDD[((Int, Int), Double)])={
    val rating_range=final_predictions_adjusted.map(x=>(x._2.toInt,1)).reduceByKey(_+_).sortByKey()
    val rating_range_till_4=rating_range.map{x=>
      var temp=x
      if (x._1==5){temp=(4,x._2)}
      temp
    }.reduceByKey(_+_)
    rating_range_till_4.sortByKey().foreach { x =>
      if(x._1==0)
        printf(">=0 and <1: " + x._2+"\n")
      if(x._1==1)
        printf(">=1 and <2: " + x._2+"\n")
      if(x._1==2)
        printf(">=2 and <3: " + x._2+"\n")
      if(x._1==3)
        printf(">=3 and <4: " + x._2+"\n")
      if(x._1==4)
        printf(">=4 " + x._2+"\n")
      if(x._1==5)
        printf("=5 " + x._2+"\n")
    }
  }
  case class User_mov_rat(UserID: Int, MovieID:Int, Pred_rating: Double)

  def print_outputfile(final_predictions_adjusted:RDD[((Int, Int), Double)])={
    val writer = new FileWriter(new File("./output.txt" ))
    writer.write("UserID,MovieID,Pred_rating\n")
    final_predictions_adjusted.collect().foreach(x=>{writer.write(x._1._1+","+x._1._2+","+x._2+"\n")})
    writer.close()
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Prateek_Agrawal_task1").setMaster("local[2]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

//    val file = "/Users/echoesofconc/Documents/USC_courses/INF553/ml-latest-small/ratings.csv"
//    val test = "/Users/echoesofconc/Documents/USC_courses/INF553/Prateek_Agrawal_hw3/testing_small.csv"

    val file = "/Users/echoesofconc/Documents/USC_courses/INF553/ml-20m/ratings.csv"
    val test = "/Users/echoesofconc/Documents/USC_courses/INF553/Prateek_Agrawal_hw3/testing_20m.csv"

    val data = sc.textFile(file, 2).cache()
    val data_test = sc.textFile(test, 2).cache()

//    Drop Header
//    val data_wo_header=dropheader(data).persist()
//    val data_test_wo_header=dropheader(data_test).persist()
//    Create Traing and testing data of the format (User ID, MovID, Rating, Time)

    val data_wo_header=dropheader(data).map(_.split(",")).map(x=>((x(0),x(1)),(x(2),x(3))))
    val data_test_wo_header=dropheader(data_test).map(_.split(",")).map(x=>((x(0),x(1)),1))
    val ratings_train=data_wo_header.subtractByKey(data_test_wo_header)
    val ratings_test=data_wo_header.subtractByKey(ratings_train)

    data_test_wo_header.unpersist()
    data_wo_header.unpersist()
    data.unpersist()
    data_test.unpersist()

//    val ratings_split = data_wo_header.map(line => line.split(",")).persist()
//    data_wo_header.unpersist()
//    data.unpersist()
//    val ratings_testing = data_test_wo_header.map(line => line.split(",")).collect()
//    data_test_wo_header.unpersist()
//    data_test.unpersist()
//
//    val ratings_train = create_training(ratings_split, ratings_testing).persist()
//    val ratings_test=create_testing(ratings_split, ratings_testing)
//    ratings_split.unpersist()
//    ratings_test.unpersist()

//    Create the model using rating_train the training data
    val rank = 1
    val numIterations = 10

//    val model=create_model(ratings_train,rank,numIterations)
//
//    model.save(sc, "/Users/echoesofconc/Documents/USC_courses/INF553/Prateek_Agrawal_hw3/myCollaborativeFilter")
    val model = MatrixFactorizationModel.load(sc, "/Users/echoesofconc/Documents/USC_courses/INF553/Prateek_Agrawal_hw3/myCollaborativeFilter")

//    Average user,Rating from training
    val user_avgrat=ratings_train.map(_ match { case ((user, mov), (rate, temp)) =>(user.toInt, (rate.toDouble,1.0))}).reduceByKey((x,y)=>(x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2)).mapValues{ case (sum, count) => (1.0 * sum) / count }
    ratings_train.unpersist()
//    Predict user_mov ratings
    val user_mov = data_test_wo_header.map(_ match { case ((user, mov),temp) =>
      (user.toInt,mov.toInt)
    })

    val predictions =
    model.predict(user_mov).map { case Rating(user, mov, rate) =>
      ((user, mov), rate)
    }

//    Combine Predictions and unpredicted user,Movies due to them being individual. Going forward we need to improve the accuracy for these predictions
    val user_mov_rat=user_mov.map(x=>(x,0.0))
    val predictions_unpredicted_combined= predictions.union(user_mov_rat).reduceByKey(_+_).map(x=>(x._1._1,(x._1._2,x._2)))
//    Combine average rating and predictions+unpredicted values
    val avg_rating_predictions_unpredicted_combined=predictions_unpredicted_combined.join(user_avgrat)
//    Generate final predictions RDD
    val final_predictions=avg_rating_predictions_unpredicted_combined.map{x=>
      var temp=((x._1,x._2._1._1),x._2._2)
      if(x._2._1._2==0.0){temp=((x._1,x._2._1._1),x._2._2)}
      if(x._2._1._2!=0.0){temp=((x._1,x._2._1._1),x._2._1._2)}
      temp
    }
//    Adjust for ratings above 5.0 and below 0.0
    val final_predictions_adjusted=final_predictions.map{x=>
      var temp=x
      if (x._2>5.0){temp=(x._1,5.0)}
      if (x._2<0.0){temp=(x._1,0.0)}
      temp
    }
//    final_predictions_adjusted.count()
    val ratesAndPreds_map = ratings_test.map(_ match { case ((user, mov), (rate, temp)) => ((user.toInt,mov.toInt),rate.toDouble)})
    val ratesAndPreds=ratesAndPreds_map.join(final_predictions_adjusted)
    val MSE = ratesAndPreds.map { case ((user, product), (r1, r2)) =>
      val err = (r1 - r2)
      err * err
    }.mean()
    val RMSE=math.sqrt(MSE)
//    Print output.txt
    print_outputfile(final_predictions_adjusted)
//    Print the predictionresults
    print_results(final_predictions_adjusted.sortByKey())
    print(RMSE+"\n")
  }
}
```